# deoplete completion from other file types

Tags: vim, autocomplete, neovim

I'm trying to use deoplete for completion and found a problem: deoplete by default doesn't complete using data from all opened files. For example, when I edit JavaScript, HTML and CSS files I can't complete word in JS file from HTML file.

I tried to put in `init.vim`:

```
call deoplete#custom#source('require_same_filetype', 0)
let g:deoplete#buffer#require#same_filetype = 0
```

Also, I tried to use `Shougo/context_filetype.vim`, but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Shugo wrote something like that [here](https://github.com/Shougo/deoplete.nvim/issues/744):

```
call deoplete#custom#var('buffer', 'require_same_filetype', v:false)
```

Hopefully it'll help.